# Convert Array List to Comma Separated String in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays

I'm using **String.Join** to attempt to turn an array list into a string that is comma separated, such as

```
xxx@xxx.com,yyy@xxx.com,zzz@xxx.com,www@xxx.com
```

I can't seem to get the syntax working.

Here's what I'm trying:

```
    for (i = 0; i < xxx; i++)
    {
        MailingList = arrayList[i].ToString();
        MailingList = string.Join(", ", MailingList.ToString());
        Response.Write(MailingList.ToString());
    }
```

Can you help me?

Thank you in advance-

Comment: What is the type of `arrayList` ?

Comment: So you want the content of your `arrayList` to be concatenated? That is, `arrayList` is a `List<string>`?

Comment: @AntonioMailtraq do you mean that the declaration is `string arrayList=...`? You wouldn't need to join anything then. More likely it's `string[] arrayList`, `List<string> arrayList` or even `ArrayList arrayList`. Which is it?

Comment: @Panagiotis arrayList.AddRange(ListBox.Items);

Comment: Please post all relevant information in the question itself. You have an ArrayList into which you are entering [ListItemCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitemcollection(v=vs.110).aspx) objects. Without this information it's impossible to give an answer that actually rungs. The question suggested you had at best an ArrayList containing either a string array or List<string> or something similar

Comment: Posting any error message might also help... your syntax is not working, fine, if it was you probably wouldn't be here, but what is exactly failing and if you get an error message, please specify it...

Comment: @Bartdude. I don't have error in the c# code; the output is wrong ,,,in output I have xxx@xxx.comyyy@xxx.comzzz@xxx.comwww@xxx.com  and don't have xxx@xxx.com, yyy@xxx.com, zzz@xxx.com, www@xxx.com

Answer (score 6):

Guessing from the name of your variable (`arrayList`), you've got `List<string[]>` or an equivalent type there.

The issue here is that you're calling `ToString()` on the array.
Try this instead:

```
for (i = 0; i < xxx; i++)
{
    var array = arrayList[i];
    MailingList = string.Join(", ", array);
    Response.Write(MailingList);
}
```

EDIT: If `arrayList` is simply an `ArrayList` containing strings, you can just do

```
Response.Write(string.Join(", ", arrayList.OfType<string>()));
```

Personally I would avoid using nongeneric collections (such as `ArrayList`) if possible and use strongly-typed collections from `System.Collections.Generic` such as `List<string>`. For example, if you have a piece of code that *depends on* that all contents of the `ArrayList` are strings, it will suffer catastrophically if you accidentally add an item that's not a string.

EDIT 2: If your `ArrayList` actually contains `System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem`s like you mentioned in your comment: `arrayList.AddRange(ListBox.Items);`, then you'll need to use this instead:

```
Response.Write(string.Join(", ", arrayList.OfType<ListItem>()));
```

Comment: Well, thanks for the feedback - could you please add what exactly is not working? Does it give an exception?

Comment: in output I have xxx@xxx.comyyy@xxx.comzzz@xxx.comwww@xxx.com

Comment: @AntonioMailtraq Try the second method which I added.

Comment: @AntonioMailtraq Add `using System.Linq;` to the top of your file.

Answer (score 2):

The second parameter for [`String.Join`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.join(v=vs.110).aspx) needs to be an `IEnumerable`. Replace `MailingList.ToString()` with `arrayList` and it should work.

Comment: Switching `for` to a `foreach` should take care of an ArrayList containing any other enumerable

Comment: @ClaudioRedi: Yes you are correct. Anything which implements IEnumerable seems to be fine, since both arrays and `IEnumerable<T>` implement it.

Comment: I believe only generic enumerable (`IEnumerable<string>`) or array would work. It may require a test and check all methods overload to confirm it though.

Comment: If it's actually an `ArrayList`, it won't work with `String.Join`. Easily fixed by LINQ `.ToArray`: http://i.imgur.com/8WKZ3WM.png

Comment: Or better yet, `OfType<string>()` in case it contains objects that aren't strings

Answer (score -1):

Initialization:

```
string result = string.Empty;
```

For value types:

```
if (arrayList != null) {
   foreach(var entry in arrayList){
      result += entry + ',';
   }
}
```

For reference types:

```
if (arrayList != null) {
   foreach(var entry in arrayList){
      if(entry != null)
         result += entry + ',';
   }
}
```

And cleanup:

```
if(result == string.Empty)
   result = null;
else
   result = result.Substring(0, result.Length - 1);
```

Comment: Why reinvent String.Join?

Comment: Also, if you're going to reinvent it, `StringBuilder` could be a better option instead of string concatenations.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I think this is personal preference. I like to write easy methods on my own instead of using the .Net stuff.

Comment: @cubrr Yea, that would be a better option :)

Answer (score -1):

most of the answers are already there, still posting a complete - working snippet

```
string[] emailListOne = { "xxx@xxx.com", "yyy@xxx.com", "zzz@xxx.com", "www@xxx.com" };
string[] emailListTwo = { "xxx@xxx1.com", "yyy@xxx1.com", "zzz@xxx1.com", "www@xxx1.com" };
string[] emailListThree = { "xxx@xxx2.com", "yyy@xxx2.com", "zzz@xxx2.com", "www@xxx.com" };
string[] emailListFour = { "xxx@xxx3.com", "yyy@xxx3.com", "zzz@xxx3.com", "www@xxx3.com" };

List<string[]> emailArrayList = new List<string[]>();
emailArrayList.Add(emailListOne);
emailArrayList.Add(emailListTwo);
emailArrayList.Add(emailListThree);
emailArrayList.Add(emailListFour);

StringBuilder csvList = new StringBuilder();
int i = 0;
foreach (var list in emailArrayList)
{
   csvList.Append(string.Join(",", list));
   if(i < emailArrayList.Count - 1)
      csvList.Append(",");
   i++;
}
Response.Write(csvList.ToString());
```

Comment: Why is this better than String.Join?

Comment: i never said that, instead am using the same, i just posted a complete code @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: @manish If you take a look at OP's code, you'll notice that he's writing to the response directly from the foreach loop, instead of first gathering all of the strings.