# How to separate an array of strings from a JSON file with commas

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I want to display the content of a Json file in a view in a project using ASP.NET MVC, but when i get the data and display it in a table in a view it looks like:

"data1data2data3data4"

How i can separate that JSON array of string with commas like:

"data1 , data2 , data3 , data4"

The JSON file has the next structure:

```
[  
   {  
      "Name":"Value",
      "Name2":[  
         "Data1",
         "Data2",
         "Data3",
         "Data4",

      ]
   }
]
```

And i display the data in a table like:

```
<table border="1">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Name2</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var element in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => element.Name)</td>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => element.Name2)</td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
</table>
```

But it looks like:

```
Name  | Name2
-----------------------------
Value | Data1Data2Data3Data4
```

and i want to display the data like:

```
Name  | Name2
-----------------------------
Value | Data1 , Data2 , Data3 , Data4
```

Any way to do this?

Edit:

I have this method to get the Json data:

```
string fileJson = File.ReadAllText(@"Path.json");
var dataJson = 
JsonConverter.DeserializeObject<List<Object>>(fileJson);
return dataJson;
```

And then called it from a controller

Comment: Can you show your C# code where you parse JSON to C# objects?

Comment: @JohanP Html.DisplayFor() helper displays a model property, it can't be used for custom string.

Comment: Sure, i added the code that i use to get the Json data

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Array List to Comma Separated String in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30916472/convert-array-list-to-comma-separated-string-in-c-sharp)

Comment: <th colspan="4">Name2</th>

Comment: I think this is not C# question. it's html question.

Comment: I would rethink on storing the data in proper format!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your second td with:

```
<td>@Html.Raw(string.Join(" , ", element.Name2))</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do `m => string.Join(" , ", element.Name2)` to get the format you want.